# Running django and wordpress on the same apache server

Tags: django, wordpress, apache

I want to run www.example.com to be accessed and managed by django. And,

www.example.com/about or www.example.com/about/...

and

www.example.com/wordpress or www.example.com/wordpress/...

to be managed by wordpress.

So, the wordpress admin will be at www.example.com/wordpress and the pages it generates will be at www.example.com/about/...

I have no idea how to do this. How can I host these two things on the same apache server?

This is my current wsgi file and the django app works at www.example.com. But when i access www.example.com/about/ it tries to go through urls.py and not find anything. how do i put my wordpress pages over here?

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias / "C:\Users\Nikunj\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\myapp\myapp\wsgi.py"

Alias / "C:\Users\Nikunj\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\myapp\myapp\"

<Directory />
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Thank you for all your help!! :)

**EDIT** this is my new file using jdi's answer but it still doesnt work:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:\Users\Nikunj\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\myapp\myapp\wsgi.py"

Alias /wordpress/ "C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-admin\"
Alias / "C:\Users\Nikunj\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\myapp\myapp\"

<Directory "C:/wamp/www/wordpress/wp-admin/">
  AllowOverride All
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory />
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Alias for '/' will override WSGIScriptAlias for '/'. Don't use Alias for '/'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create multiple directory entries in your apache conf: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directory

One is set up for wordpress, and one is set up for django. Right now, every bit of traffic is always going to your django app.

It might look something like this (just guessing):

```
Alias /about/ "C:/path/to/wordpress/"
Alias /wordpress/ "C:/path/to/wordpress/wp-admin/"

Alias / "C:/Users/Nikunj/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/myapp/myapp/"

<Directory "C:/path/to/wordpress/">
  AllowOverride All
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory />
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I cannot get this to work. It still goes to django and searches in urls.py. 
Here is what i wrote:

`Alias /wordpress/ "C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-admin\"`

`<Directory /wordpress/>`

`AllowOverride All`

`Order allow,deny`

`Allow from all`

`</Directory>`


`Alias / "C:\Users\Nikunj\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 
Workspace\myapp\myapp\"`

`WSGIScriptAlias / "C:\Users\Nikunj\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\myapp\myapp\wsgi.py"`

`<Directory />`

`Order allow,deny`

`Allow from all`

`</Directory>`

Comment: I have no idea how to format the code in the comment. I'll put it in as an edit.

Comment: Did you try it the way I actually showed you? I think you have the directory value backwards. The alias maps the url to the filesystem path. Then the directory catches that filesystem pattern

Answer (score 1):

Final answer:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/wamp/www/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py"

Alias /about/ "C:/wamp/www/wordpress/"
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/wordpress/">
  AllowOverride All
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/wamp/www/myapp">
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

www.example.com <- django

www.example.com/about <- wp

Thanks!